# Android regular user login loses group information when su to another user in an ssh session

Tags: android, ssh, su

What I'm doing:

- I've built GNU emacs for native use on an phone.
- I run emacs in daemon mode on the phone, so I connect to it anytime with emacsclient, to continue working with regular files, run processes, etc.
- When logging in from the terminal on the phone, I'm currently user 10157, everything works:

  $ id

  uid=10157(10157) gid=10157(10157)
  groups=10157(10157),1015(1015),1023(1023),1028(1028),3003(3003)
- When I connect via ssh to the phone from a PC (I use DigiSSHd on the phone), it logs me in as a regular user 10282, everything works:

  $ id

  uid=10282 gid=10282 groups=1015(1015),1023(1023),1028(1028),3003(3003)

Emacs runs fine etc. However, this way I can't connect via emacsclient to the emacs process running under user 10157. This is desirable, since I don't want to start two emacs processes, since I want to continue working with files that I have open in emacs under user 10157.

Therefore:
`$ su - 10157`

Fine, I can run emacs etc. However, I cannot access the web.

```
$ ping -c1 google.com
You must have internet permissions to use ping.  Aborting.
$ id

uid=10157(10157) gid=10157(10157) groups=10157(10157)
```

Thus I'm no longer in group 3003, necessary for internet access, besides other groups also.

Why does this group info get stripped, and how can I remedy this, so I can continue accessing the web when su as this user under ssh?

Comment: #justsaying What a coincidence: "27ca8cd  Merge "ping: remove group check" by Nick Kralevich - 14 days ago" https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/ping

Comment: I am pretty sure the issue is with your Superuser app. Check my answer.

Comment: @mcandre Instead [I'm pretty sure it's a problem in the AndroidManifest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15906960/412808).

Answer (score 4):

When i run the command:

```
busybox --list
```

I don't see su in the list.

```
su --help
```

shows Superuser.apk in the help text. It means **su** is provided by Superuser app.

I followed the steps described by you and i could su as another user and still have internet permission as shown below.

[image: terminal]

[image]

I have the following apps installed.

- BusyBox v1.18.5-Stericson
- Superuser v3.0.7
- Terminal Emulator v1.0.45
- SSHDroid v1.9.6

*Suggestion*:
I think the issue is with su on your device. You may try this one.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.noshufou.android.su

If i just use adb shell without running SSHDroid still i can su as another user with internet permission.

[image]

Note: The BusyBox id command doesn't show groups information always.

[image]

Comment: @mcandre I can confirm this. The `su` binary can be found either in `/system/bin/su` or in `/system/xbin/su` and is not a part of BusyBox. Where do you get your `su` from - Superuser, SuperSu, or something else?

Comment: @appsroxcom Yes, I'm using `su` from the Superuser app. Could you provide an example using the username rather than the ID?

Comment: @appsroxcom Look again at your screenshot. Groups are missing. Like this. http://i.imgur.com/9hSXwQe.png When I `su - <sameuser>`, I lose these groups.

Comment: @mcandre, That's fine. But can you ping or read sdcard when you su - <sameuser> ? I can.

Comment: @mcandre, The BusyBox id command seems have some issue in displaying group information. Check this. http://i.imgur.com/sKzHieu.png

Answer (score 2):

According to the standard man page for `su` (from a linux box)

> When - is used, it must be specified as the last su option. The other forms (-l and --login) do not have this restriction.

Based on that, try

```
$ su 10157 -
```

Comment: In my setup, I'm not even using `su -`, I'm using `su someuser`.

Comment: you need to use `-` to "Provide an environment similar to what the user would expect had the user logged in directly."

Comment: BusyBox `su -l u0_a41` drops the groups on my phone, as does `su u0_a41 -`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably missing something here because this seems way too obvious but why not just 'sudo -u 10157' your emacs program?

you'd still have access to the net and your emacs would be working. or did I miss something important?

Comment: I need to keep the parent's group permissions, or I lose access to the SD card. And sadly, BusyBox `su` is dropping group permissions in Android.

Answer (score 0):

Permissions are not environment variables that can be inherited via `su -`.

Moreover, gid are are [hard coded](https://github.com/cgjones/android-system-core/blob/master/include/private/android_filesystem_config.h) and their associations with each APP uid cannot be changed after installation.

**10157** should be the uid of the **DigiSSHd** application, thus you could try to rebuild it after changing the [AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/ezh/android-component-DigiSSHD/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) to require the proper [permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html).

You can find something useful [here](http://programming4.us/mobile/1290.aspx) and [here](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html#RequestingPermissions).

The same should work for **BusyBox** (see [here](https://code.google.com/p/busybox-android/source/browse/trunk/app/Free/AndroidManifest.xml)).

However, you could open some security hole by enabling NETWORK access through such applications.